# Convert numeric column to time

Tags: sql, time

I have a table of employee shifts which include shift start time and shift end time. The  start time and end time columns are numeric with a full stop between hour and minute:

```
 8.00
15.10
 7.00
22.00
 7.00
```

How can I convert these columns to time? I also need to calculate the difference between start time and end time in hours and minutes to work out the shift length.

Comment: Which SQL engine? And what is the numeric value type precisely (E.g. decimal or float)?

Comment: @KotaMori, I'm going out on a limb and going to say that the column's type is  not numeric and we're looking at varchar or a similar type

Answer (score 0):

In **`Sql Server`** use following code

```
 SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(9), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 112) + '22:00');
```

You can replace **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** to your date

Ex:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(9), CONVERT(DATE,'2022-01-25'), 112) + '22:00');
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

In `Sql Server` use following code

```
declare @seconds numeric
set @seconds = 12366
select convert(char(8), dateadd(second, @seconds, ''), 114)
```